# EPL syntax wrong

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I am very new to EPL queries.
Wrote this and it is throwing syntax error.

```
@Name('ExpressionTotalQuantitySoFar')
@Description('Gets the total quantity of a symbol so far')
create expression totalQuantitySoFar{ (TAX) =>
    (Select sum(T.quantity) from TaxlotWindow as T where T.symbol = TAX.symbol and T.taxlotId < TAX.taxlotId)
};


create variable double totQty = 5.0 ;
@Name('ExpressionLongDebitBalanceTaxlotNoBox')
@Description('Check is if a trade side is invalid, returns rue for invalid statements')
create expression longDebitBalanceTaxlotNoBox{ (SECUR,TAX,ORD,AUE,FX) =>
    totQty = totalQuantitySoFar(TAX)

    case when (totQty > 0)
        then cashImpactBase(SECUR,TAX,ORD,AUE,FX)*(-1)
    else
        0.0
    end

};
```

It gives syntax error near case.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Always include the syntax error text when posting. Else how is one supposed to be able to help.

My tip would be to simplify until the syntax is fine. Then add back stuff.

Most likely this strange declaration "totQty=.." is the cause as its wrong. EPL expressions are not a programming language and don't allow variable declarations like in Java or Scala. Perhaps just use a Java static method to compute instead of you need a programming language.